# virtuoso triples insertion through nodejs code

Tags: node.js, http, curl, post, virtuoso

I want to insert triples into my graph inside the Virtuoso through Nodejs. So, first i have checked it with the CURL commands and it is working. Now i am trying to do the same with the nodejs code, but it is not working and also not showing any error....
Here is the reference: 
For curl command (example 2 in the below web page):

> http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfinsertmethodshttppost/

For Node.js the code is:

```js
var triples = 

"http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>"+
  "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#User> ."+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>"+
  "<Kingsley Uyi Idehen> ."+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#creator_of> <http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com/weblog/kidehen@openl"+"inksw.com%27s%20BLOG%20%5B127%5D/1300>";
    var myData= JSON.stringify("INSERT IN GRAPH <http://mygraph.org>  { "+triples+" }";
            
    var header = {
                  'Content-Type': "application/sparql-query",
                  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(myData)
                 };
             
     var options = {
                  host: localhost,
                  port: 8890,
                  auth: 'dba:dba',
                  path: '/DAV/home/dba/rdf_sink/mydata',
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: header
              };
              
     var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
                  res.setEncoding('utf-8');
                  var responseString = '';
                  res.on('data', function(data) {
                     console.log('On data:' + data);
                  });
                  res.on('end', function() {});
              });
              req.on('error', function(e) {
                  console.log('On Error:' + e);
              });
    req.write(myData);
    req.end();
```

The code is not showing error but also not inserting any triples in the virtuoso database..Please suggest..

Comment: Just at first glance, it appears that your `var triples` declaration is incorrect, as several URIs start with `http:` instead of `<http:`.  There may be other errors.

Comment: oh....thats just "typo error" while asking..but it is not working after correcting it...

Comment: You've retyped your node.js code here? Please copy-and-paste instead. I see more errors in the `var triples` declaration now than before!

Comment: done please check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, errors remain in your inline data.  You have --

```js
var triples = 

"http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>"+
  "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#User> ."+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>"+
  "<Kingsley Uyi Idehen> ."+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this>"+
  "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#creator_of> <http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com/weblog/kidehen@openl"+"inksw.com%27s%20BLOG%20%5B127%5D/1300>";
```

A literal is wrapped in `<>` instead of `""`; the first URI is missing the opening `<`; some whitespace which may be syntactically important is missing...

Should become (with some extra whitespace adjustments for readability) --

```js
var triples = 

  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this> "+
     "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> "+
        "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#User> . "+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this> "+
     "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "+
        "\"Kingsley Uyi Idehen\" . "+
  "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/person/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this> "+
     "<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#creator_of> "+
        "<http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com/weblog"+
           "/kidehen@openlinksw.com%27s%20BLOG%20%5B127%5D/1300> . ";
```

I would have expected your original to result in some error output (which might yet be found in the Virtuoso log file, though it was possibly suppressed/dropped somewhere in your `node.js` interaction), rather than a silent failure; still, the above may resolve the issue.